# How to Left join and remove the common fields between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following tables: 
table1 (p, crc, rti, l1)
table2 ( p, crc, rti)

I want to find all records from table1 with equal values for p and crc with table2 but remove those records that with the same values for p and crc have different values for rti in two tables 
I tried to

```
Select * FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.p = t2.p and t1.crc = t2.crc
```

But don't know how to remove the common records

Comment: your title says "remove common fields" and your question says "remove common records". which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. Assuming you have records in the tables like this:
Table 1:

1. (p, crc, rti, l1) values (1, 23, 6, 8)
2. (p, crc, rti, l1) values (1, 23, 7, 5)
3. (p, crc, rti, l1) values (1, 23, 9, 2)

Table 2:

1. (p, crc, rti) values (1, 23, 7)
2. (p, crc, rti) values (1, 23, 8)
3. (p, crc, rti) values (1, 23, 9)

If you want to show all the records from table 1 where table1.rti is not equal to table2.rti, then try the below. This would give you table 1 row 1 (above).

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on 
     t1.p = t2.p AND t1.crc = t2.crc
WHERE
     t1.rti <> t2.rti
```

Based on your comment below, maybe try the MINUS operator.

```
SELECT * FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on 
     t1.p = t2.p AND t1.crc = t2.crc
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies,

Comment: Thanks for your replies, my Q is that if I have Values (1, 23, 6, 8), (1, 33, 6, 7) in table1 and values (1, 23, 1) and (1, 40, 1) in table2, I want me query return just (1, 33, 6, 8) from table1 and not return (1, 23, 6, 8) from table1 because there is value(1, 23, 1) in table2 of which t1.p = t2.p and t1.crc = t2.crc

Comment: Is this a correct approach? SELECT * from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON t1.p = t2.p and t1.crc = t2.crc WHERE t2.rti IS NULL

Comment: Based on your comment above, I don't think that will give you what you are looking for. Using your example, if table1 has values {(1,23,6,8),(1,33,6,7)} and table 2 has values {(1,23,1),(1,40,1)}, then `SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON t1.p = t2.p AND t1.crc = t2.crc WHERE t2.rti IS NULL` would not return {(1,33,6,8)}. This value would never be returned by joining table1 and table2 on p and crc. Did you try my last suggestion? That should work. `SELECT * FROM table1
MINUS
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on 
     t1.p = t2.p AND t1.crc = t2.crc`

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to list the columns you actually want.  But, if the only columns you want are the join keys, then you can use `USING`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     USING (p, crc);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems as if you want to exclude all records from `table1`, where `table2` contains at least one record with same `p` and same `crc` but different `rti`.
This could be written as "Get all records from table1, where no record with same `p` and same `crc` but different `rti` exists in `table2`".

```
select * from table1 t1
where not exists (
  select * from table2 t2
  where t1.p = t2.p and
        t1.crc = t2.crc and
        t1.rti <> t2.rti)
```

Hope I got you right.